# select query with join to get rows where values from a column will be in a single row on the basis of primary key in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select data with oracle join where rows with same ids will have data in a single row with multiple columns i.e

Table 1 :

```
ID         DATA
1          test1
2          test2
3          test3
4          test4
```

Table 2 :

```
ID         DATA
1          data1
1          data2
2          data3
2          data4
```

My Sql is like :

select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 
on t1.id = t2.id

output should be like :

```
ID       value1      value2
1         data1       data2
2         data3       data4
```

Comment: Always 2 data per id?

Comment: In addition to jarlh's great question... Does it matter which data goes in what column?  It seems you're after a pivot of some sort; but we don't know if it needs to be dynamic or not and how to arrange the data.

Comment: no , it is dynamic there can be multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

If only 2 data per ID you could use a analytic to assign a row number for each ID and use conditional logic and aggregation to pivot the data manually...

I use a common table expression (CTE) to generate a row number so we can use it to specify the order in which the data is put in the columns for an ID.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Data, row_number() over (partition by ID order by data) RN
  FROM table1)
SELECT ID
     , max(case when RN = 1 then data end) as Value1
     , max(case when RN = 2 then data end) as Value2
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID
```

Or you could use pivot statement itself.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Data, row_number() over (partition by ID order by data) RN
  FROM table1)
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT data, RN
      FROM CTE t)
PIVOT (max(data)
       for RN in (1,2))
ORDER BY ID
```

If however you have a dynamic number of data elements per ID then you have to write dynamic pivot. Several examples already exist on stack for this.